# Spectrum3d, Error with gstreamer

Tags: software-installation, gstreamer

this is my first question and after playing around with terminal for the first time and terminal/linux in general, I am trying to use a cool sound spectrogram software called spectrum3D, I have compiled all the necessary dependencies required to run this software but it seems after 2 days of fiddling around I have encountered a brick wall and need assistance from the vast experience here.

My ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS, It seems to have come prepacked with 0.10 gstreamer - I tried updating that to the 1.0 gstreamer and even the newest 1.8.2 gstreamer but I always encounter the following error:

```
Sudo spectrum3d
password for onepercent:
Spectrum3d 2.5.0
please report any bug to nadaeck@hotmail.com
argc=1
Getting saved rom rc file
WARNING : RC file doesn't exist or cannot be open; this is normal if you run
Spectrum3d for the first time;
**
ERROR:gstreamer.c:45:initGstreamer: assertion failed: (equalizer)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried the default 0.10 gstreamer, 1.0 gstreamer and the newest 1.9.2

any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install the `gstreamer-plugins-good` package of your gstreamer version.